# Cloning bit-bucket repository using shell script caused each repository in the directory to be concatenated with '$'\r and now text wraps in terminal

Tags: regex, linux, git, ubuntu

- Hello everyone, I ran shell script

my_repo_list.sh

- which simply contained a list of git clone commands:

git clone https://repo@bitbucket.org/handle/group.git repoName1

git clone https://repo@bitbucket.org/handle/group.git repoName2

git clone https://repo@bitbucket.org/handle/group.git repoName3

git clone https://repo@bitbucket.org/handle/group.git repoName4

- And instead of just a repo name:

repoName1

repoName2

repoName3

repoName4

- The names' of the repos inside the directory are in the form:

'repoName1'$'\r'

'repoName2'$'\r'

'repoName3'$'\r'

'repoName4'$'\r'

Sorry for the terrible formatting any clues about this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Diagnosis: your `my_repo_list.sh` script had CR-LF line endings instead of the LF-only line endings that Linux shells need.

Each `git clone` command was thus:

```
git clone https://repo@bitbucket.org/handle/group.git repoName1<CR>
```

instead of:

```
git clone https://repo@bitbucket.org/handle/group.git repoName1
```

where the `<CR>` indicates a literal control-M or `$'\r'` character.  So each of your new directory names ends with a literal control-M.  Whatever is *displaying* these names is cleverly showing it in a form that your shell (probably bash) will probably interpret correctly.

Fix: rename each directory to eliminate the carriage-return:

```
for i in repoName1 repoName2 repoName3 repoName4; do
    mv ${i}$'\r' ${i}
done
```

and next time, pay attention to the line endings in your scripts.